# Proper way to move unique_ptr array into another

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have an array contained in a std::unique_ptr and I want to move the contents into another array of the same type. Do I need to write a loop to move the elements one by one or can I use something like std::move?

```
const int length = 10;
std::unique_ptr<int[]> data(new int[length]);
//Initialize 'data'
std::unique_ptr<int[]> newData(new int[length]);
//Fill 'newData' with the contents of 'data'
```

EDIT: Also, what if the arrays are different sizes?

Comment: You appear to be using `length`, which is a const, for the size of both of them. So is one larger or are they the same size?

Comment: do both data and newData have the same scope?

Comment: Assume no. However, how does this affect things?

Comment: do you reference data sometime later? If not than std::move or swap() would do the trick

Comment: If you assume data can be thrown away, what is the proper syntax for std::move?

Comment: You could use `std::swap(data, newData)`.

Comment: regarding the edited part - are you modelling std::vector<int>.resize()?

Comment: That's roughly what I'm going for, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given destination array defined as:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> destPtr(new int[destLength]);
```

And source array defined as:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> srcPtr(new int[srcLength]);
```

Where its guaranteed that `srcLength <= destLength`, you can use std::move as follows:

```
const auto &srcBegin = srcPtr.get();
std::move(srcBegin, std::next(srcBegin, srcLength), destPtr.get());
```

Comment: for primitive types such as 'int'  std:move is an equivalent of std::copy

Answer (score 2):

You can use `swap`:

```
#include<memory>
#include<cassert>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> a{new int[42]};
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> b{};
    a[0] = 42;
    a.swap(b);
    assert(b[0] == 42);
}
```

> Also, what if the arrays are different sizes?

You can use `swap`.

---

Consider that `length` isn't an information that comes along with the unique pointer.
Because of that, you still have to *swap* the `length`s of the two arrays somehow.

Moreover, if you want to move data, but also you want to maintain room for extra data in the second array, a possible approach would be the classical `for` loop with a `std::move` to actually *move* the data from `a` to `b`.
More expensive (linear complexity, fair enough).

Answer (score 1):

Initialization using `std::move`. The data's content will be discarded:

```
 std::unique_ptr<int[]> newData = std::move(data);
```

> what if array of different size?

I presume it is something like:

```
 const int length = 10;
 std::unique_ptr<int[]> data(new int[length]);
 //Initialize 'data'

 ...

 const int length2 = 20;
 std::unique_ptr<int[]> newData(new int[length2]);
 std::copy_n(data.get(), std::min(length, length2), newData.get());
```

If `newData` has a fixed size consider using  `std::array<int, SIZE>` in place of `int[]` to avoid type decay.

Comment: And what about for a general case where they may not be the same size?

Comment: @VictorStone: Yes of course - `new` doesn't know what the size is, and the type `int[]` doesn't know either.

Comment: But the goal would be to retain the size of the destination container.